# How to make DataGrip stop adding quotes around names?

Tags: datagrip

Whenever I use the autocomplete in DataGrip, be it a table or a column, it automatically adds quotes around each name, though they are not necessary.
That means that I get a query that looks like this:

```
select "col1", "col2" from "table"
```

I've tried changing the SQL dialect, that didn't change a thing. Any ideas?

Comment: What database so you use? And what do you have in this setting: https://ibb.co/kB3D6m?

Comment: It says "unquote", and I use Vertica

Comment: Can you please show the screenshot of the whole Word Case block in SQL code style setting? And what dialect do you use for Vertica scripts?